# Date Transformation in R

Tags: r

I'm facing a very minor issue, but somehow can't resolve it.

When I'm importing a csv file that has date, the date is coming in "%Y-%m-%d" format. But I want it to be in "%d-%m-%Y" format. I tried "as.Date" to transform it. But it's not working.

The data structure look like this after importing:

```
Date        Share_Val
21/01/2015   20
22/01/2015   19
23/01/2015   21
24/01/2015   23
25/01/2015   26
```

But when I'm importing the file by read.csv, the data look like the following:

```
Date        Share_Val
01/21/2015   20
01/22/2015   19
01/23/2015   21
01/24/2015   23
01/25/2015   26
```

I tried lubridate. But it didn't help. 
Sam's result comes exactly the way I wanted. But when I'm trying the following, it's not coming

```
data$date<-format(as.Date(data$date,"%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Can anybody please give me any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give a more precise example, like the input string you're seeing?

Comment: Look at package `lubridate`

Comment: `format(as.Date("2015-09-21"), "%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I've put the reply to all for your suggestions in the question itself, as Frank wanted to be bit more precise.

Comment: @SamThomas seems a bit off in his formatting "/" vs "-". but `format(as.Date("21/01/2015"), "%d/%m/%Y")` should work... though as Frank says, your problem is not clearly described.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks Alex for your suggestion! I tried to give a small example to explain my problem. Sam's answer works when I'm taking 1 date. But how to transform all dates in "Date" variable.

Comment: @Alex my comment was made prior to the example data

Comment: `21/01/2015` is a character vector of length 1. Replace that with your date vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps.  Note the `stringsAsFactors`.  If your `Date` field is a factor, you will need `data$Date <- as.character(data$Date)` first

```
data <- data.frame(Date = c("21/01/2015", "22/01/2015", "23/01/2015", 
        "24/01/2015", "25/01/2015"), Share_Val=c(20, 19, 21, 23, 26), 
         stringsAsFactors=F)

format(as.Date(data$Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "21-01-2015" "22-01-2015" "23-01-2015" "24-01-2015" "25-01-2015"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam! Your answer worked perfectly fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

I think you may be misunderstanding how Dates work in R. A variable (or column) of class `Date` is stored internally as the number of days since 1970-01-01. When you print a `Date` variable, it is displayed using the `%Y-%m-%d` format. The `as.Date(...)` function converts character to Date. The `format=...` argument controls *how the character string is interpreted*, not how the result is displayed, as in:

```
as.Date("02/05/2015", format="%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2015-02-05"
as.Date("02/05/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y")
# [1] "2015-05-02"
```

So in the first case the string is interpreted as 05 Feb, in the second 02 May. Note that in both cases the result is *displayed* (printed) in `%Y-%m-%d` format.

Comment: Thanks jlhoward! I was not aware of this. This is really helpful, even though not exactly answering my question. Thanks again.